# Mapping route to another route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I am developing an application in the Laravel 5.2 which must have a friendly URL-s. This is not problem with the regular way, where the {slug} wildcard is handled by a controller but I want to make it in a different way.

For now I have only two controllers:

- `ProductsController@show` to show details product
- `CategoriesController@show` to show selected category with listing products which are assigned to it

And routes:

```
Route::get('product/{product}', 'ProductsCategory@show')->name('product.show');
Route::get('category/{category}', 'CategoriesController@show')->name('category.show');
```

So when I want to echo a just use `route('product.show', compact('product'))`

Nothing special until I want to handle different URL-s which are fetched from a database. I thought it will be possible to make an another routes which are assigned to existing and when I use a `route(...)` helper it will be handled automatically. But it is not. So for example I have a new URL:

```
domain.com/new-url-for-product.html
```

so by route it should be assigned to the regular 'product.show' route with some ID, which is handled by route model binder for {product} wildcard. The same for `route(..)` helper it should print friendly URL-s.

I don't know if my strategy is good. How do you handle with the similar problems?

Comment: your question description are not enough to understand your problem, please elaborate it little more, So the community provide better solution.

Answer (score 1):

of course route will handle this automatically. have a look into this. I am just giving you example, you have to set this code as per your need.

```
route('product.show', 'product'=>'new-url-for-product.html');
```

will generate this

> domain.com/new-url-for-product.html

```
route('product.show', 'product'=>'new-url2-for-product.html');
```

will generate this URL

> domain.com/new-url2-for-product.html

and so on, and then you have to handle all this in your controller method.
eg: your controller method for this route is `ProductsCategory@show` which is

```
public function show($product){
 if($product == 'new-url-for-product.html'){
  //perform this
 }

 if($product == 'new-url2-for-product.html'){
  //perform this
 }
}
```

this just an example, you have to map this according to your need

**Edited** Here is the example I tested it

```
Route::get('/product/{product}.html', ['as'=>'product.show', 'uses'=>'ProductsCategory@show']);
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Do you know how to achieve that using Route Model Binding, where {category} and {product} are models?

Comment: Here is the best example by Laravel documentation for Model Binding. I hope this will help you, let me know if you want anything else in this regard
[follow here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: I am familiar with the documentation. The thing is that I like to use in target controller method (ex. ProductsControllers@show) a product model which is binded to a database model.This is why I would like to implement route-to-route strategy. Do you know how to extend the Route class and if this is a good manner? Maybe there is quite different way?

Comment: Well, I am not much familiar with extension of route class.